# Combine multiple numpy arrays into one of different shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I have four different numpy arrays of different shapes:

```
(2580, 100)
(2580, 237)
(2580, 8)
(2580, 37)
```

How can I combine all the arrays together to a single numpy array?

Gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2580,237) into shape (2580)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((2580, 100))
>>> b = np.zeros((2580, 237))
>>> c = np.zeros((2580, 8))
>>> d = np.zeros((2580, 37))
>>> e = np.concatenate((a, b, c, d), axis=1)
>>> e.shape
(2580, 382)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [np.c_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) to concatenate along axis

```
import numpy as np
f = np.zeros(shape=(5,4))
s = np.zeros(shape=(5,6))
t = np.zeros(shape=(5,16))
res=np.c_[f,s,t]
res.shape
(5,26)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just us np.concatenate

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(2580, 100)
b = np.random.rand(2580, 237)
c = np.random.rand(2580, 8)
d = np.random.rand(2580, 37)

e = np.concatenate((a, b, c, d), axis = 1)
print(e.shape) 
# (2580, 382)
```